# Uncaught TypeError When Linking OpenStreetMap API to Website

Tags: javascript, html

The frontend of my checkout page has a woocomerce form several fields I am  trying to link to an OpenStreetMap API as a plugin. However after loading the .js script and activating the plugin whenever I load the checkout page I get an

> Uncaught TypeError: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null
> (setting 'onclick')at geocoding.js?ver=1.0:8:26

message in the console. Here is the code I am using:

```
// Get the Place Order button
var placeOrderButton = document.getElementById('place_order');

// Check if script has been loaded successfully
console.log('Geocoding script loaded.');

// Add an event listener to the button
placeOrderButton.onclick = function() {
  // Get the form data
  var formData = {
    country: document.querySelector('input[name="billing_country"]').value,
    street: document.querySelector('input[name="billing_address_1"]').value,
    city: document.querySelector('input[name="billing_city"]').value,
    county: document.querySelector('input[name="billing_state"]').value,
  };

  // Construct the URL with the form data
  var url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?' + 'q=' + formData.street + ', ' + formData.city + ', ' + formData.county + ', ' + formData.country + '&format=json';

  // Send the API request
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // Get the latitude and longitude values from the response
      var lat = data[0].lat;
      var lon = data[0].lon;

      // Do something with the latitude and longitude values
      console.log('Latitude: ' + lat);
      console.log('Longitude: ' + lon);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Log any errors that occur
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
};
```

The error statement highlights the "function() {" portion of the code. I have tried using the field names as well as installing third-party checkout page managers to get the element ID but still, the error persists. What could I be doing wrong

The expected output is the latitude and longitude coordinates in the console tab of the browser developer tools. I suspect it might be an issue with improper Iding of the woocommerce checkout form elements. So if you might have an idea how to get the actual woocommerce checkout form element IDs it should help I think.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? It sounds like `placeOrderButton` might be null

Comment: I used the console.log('Geocoding script loaded.'); snippet to check if the placeOrderButton might be null however it always returns 'Geocoding script loaded.' in the browser developer tools console.

Also when inspecting the source code of the error in the browser developer tools it highlights the "function() {" portion of the code so I think the problem might be with the placeOrderButton.onclick function

Comment: `console.log('Geocoding script loaded.'); snippet to check if the placeOrderButton might be null`...that doesn't check anything. You don't get an error immediately when getElementbyId doesn't return anything, you just end up with a null variable sitting there.

Comment: `I think the problem might be with the placeOrderButton.onclick function`...yes, as I said, the problem is because `placeOrderButton` is null...therefore you can't assign an `onclick` handler to it, because that variable doesn't contain a HTML element. That's precisely what `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')` is telling you.

Comment: The root cause of that must be because, at the time you are running this code, there is no HTML element in your page with `id="place_order"`. Obviously we have no context to know when you're running this code, or when/if such an element gets loaded into your page. At the very least, wrapping this code in a DOMContentLoaded event might help, assuming the place_order element is rendered at the initial page load (and not added aftewards by JS/AJAX)

Comment: Okay wrapped the code in a DOM content loaded, addEventListener but still the console shows the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> and the error source code highlights the "= function() {" portion of the code..

Comment: I think it might be an issue with the element Id labeling, but the problem is I have checked the element ids from the developer console and went through a number of iterations "billing_country", "billing_country_field" I even downloaded a checkout page plugin that gave me the element ID "country-6021728823" but still the problem persisits

Comment: Can you find the "place_order" element in the developer console? Or least on the page, find the button you're trying to handle the click of, and right-click and inspect it, to see what its ID is?

Comment: Yes, this is the script associated with it:

 <button type="submit" class="button alt wp-element-button" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">Place order</button>

so from this, the id should be "place_order" which is the same as in the script, but also to mention the form used is a woocommerce template form for their checkout page so I don't know if that affects anything

Comment: It shouldn't, unless either a) the button is loaded asynchronously into the page via JS/AJAX (in which case it won't exist at the time your script runs, if your script runs when the page is first loaded) or b) the button is within an iframe. If it's the former, you could potentially solve this by using delegated events, or by working what triggers the element to be loaded into the page, and delaying your script until that's happened

Comment: Well I wrapped the script in a setTimeout function and then wrapped it again in a DOM ContentLoaded addEventListenenr so it doesn't have the error message when it loads but instead the error message only shows after pressing the place order button instead. I tried referencing the place order button using the name instead of the ID but still doesn't change a thing. Error still occurs after clicking the place order button...

Comment: Surely it must a different error though, in that situation? A better approach, if you can't figure out exactly how/when it's loaded into the page, is probably to use [delegated events](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/event-delegation-javascript/). That way, you bind the click handler to an element which definitely exists (it can even be `document`, and then only at runtime, when the click occurs, does it try to find the specific element which was clicked - and obviously it can then find it, because it's just been clicked.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, apparently when using woocommerce template forms it is difficult to reference the form fields using ID identifiers. So when you pass out a code it views the form as empty without any fields. I managed to solve this by building my own form and then attaching the relevant form field element IDs to the code. I worked pretty fine...

Answer (score 1):

It is evident from the error message that `placeOrderButton` is null by the time you try to assign to its `onclick` property. Either the id used in `document.getElementById('place_order');` is wrong or the element is not yet present in the DOM at the time of execution.

Maybe the plugin has some mechanism for alerting you of when it is done loading, and you have to wait for that to happen before trying to add the onclick listener (provided the issue is that the plugin generates the button and that you try to look it up too soon).

Comment: Is there a way to delay this with code as my internet upload and download speeds tend to be slow from time to time and this might also contribute to the null reading

Comment: As an experiment you could use something like 
`setTimeout(function() {
    const placeOrderButton = document.getElementById('place_order');
    placeOrderButton.onclick = function() {
      ...
    }
  }, 10000) // Delay the execution for 10 seconds`

But this is not a suitable solution to the problem. I think you need to figure out the order of execution of the involved code and maybe check if the plugin exposes some mechanism that you can use to get notified of when it has added its stuff to the page (againt, I am guessing a bit about what's going on here).

Comment: So I wrapped the script in the setTimeout function and then wrapped it again in a DOM ContentLoaded addEventListenenr. This time the error does not show up on loading, it only shows up after clicking the place order button. I think this could be caused by having the wrong element id for the button, however when checking the element tab in the developer console it shows that the id is "place-order" however I'll try referencing the button by the name instead of the ID and see if it works

Comment: Yes, then it does sound like the id must be wrong. Note that in the code you use `"place_order"` while in your last comment you stated `"place-order"` (underscore vs hyphen). Could that simply be the issue perhaps?